# C++ nested class inside of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I have a template class LinkedList, which depends on the template type T.
Inside of the class LinkedList, there's a nested class Node, which also depends T.
I try to implement Node class in a seperate .h/.cc files, but failed somehow.

The LinkedList.h is:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
    class Node;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;
};
```

BaseNode.h is:

```
template<typename kOwner>
class BaseNode {
    // some definition
}
```

Node.h is:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList<T>::Node : public BaseNode<LinkedList<T>>{
private:
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
    void Start();
}
```

Node.cc is:

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Node(MetadataManager *metadata_manager) :
    BaseNode(metadata_manager){}

template<typename T>
void ListedList<T>::Node::Start() {
    // do some operations
}
```

The error I got is

```
error: member initializer 'BaseNode' does not name a non-static data member or base class
        BaseNode(metadata_manager) {
```

Can someone tell me how to implement it please?

Comment: "failed somehow"? Can you be more precise please? What goes wrong? And you should always define templates in header files.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `void typename` -- no, take out `typename`. What's after it isn't a type, it's a member function. And even then, the template definition is only visible in `Node.cc`. It should go in `Node.h`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: I'm working with the legacy code with my teammate, one of my responsibility is to templatize the current classes, i'm afraid I have no choice but to implement the nested class in .h/.cc file seperately.

Comment: @Dentiny You can't unless you explicitly instantiate every version of the template that will ever be used.

Comment: Yes, since there's only two versions, I actually did explicit instantiation

Comment: @Dentiny Okay then the compile-time error is likely due to that `typename` after `void` which shouldn't be there. What follows isn't a type.

Comment: After I remove the typename keyword, another error occurs: member initializer 'BaseNode' does not name a non-static data member or base class
Here, I'm trying to call the ctor of the templated BaseNode

Comment: My advice if you get compiler errors always post the exact text of the error messages in the question so we don't have to play a game of guess what the errors are. It also makes for a better question for future readers.

Comment: And what line of code does that occur on?

Comment: node.cc:6:2: error: member initializer 'BaseNode' does not name a non-static data member or base class
        BaseNode(metadata_manager) {

Comment: `#include "node.h"

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(
 MetadataManagerInterface<T> *metadata_manager) :
 BaseNode(metadata_manager) {
}`

Comment: btw, how could you use the code block format on the comment/

Comment: Use ` before and after the code with no spaces between ` and the code

Comment: You may just want to edit the question with additional information

Comment: You don't inherit from `BaseNode`, you inherit from `BaseNode<LinkedList<T>>`. Change the initializer list appropriately: `: BaseNode<LinkedList<T>>(metadata_manager) { }`

Comment: You might be confused about that because you can omit the template arguments within a template type itself, but `BaseNode` _isn't_ the type you're defining here. However, in this context `LinkedList<T>` is the same thing as `LinkedList` since you _are_ in the context of that type, so you _could_ simplify both the inheritance and the initializer list to `BaseNode<LinkedList>`, but you still have to give the arguments to `BaseNode`. This is because you could inherit from `BaseNode<int>` and `BaseNode<float>`, for example. They are not the same type, so just `BaseNode` would be ambiguous.

Comment: One thing that strikes me, `Node.h` really should have `#include "BaseNode.h"` because that's a direct dependency.  You should not rely on other source files having to (precariously) have already included the direct dependencies for you code.  If this isn't the case, it'd be nice if the code provided was a complete [mcve], it would take a lot of the guesswork out of trying to help.

Comment: Yes, i have to say I'm quite confused about the template stuff...And there's link error after object file compilation, Jeus...

Comment: `void ListedList<T>::Node::Start()` isn't declared anywhere; probably supposed to be `LinkedList` and not `ListedList`.

Comment: Ah that's my typo

Comment: I recommend that you test the code provided to see that it actually reproduces the problem you've encountered.  If the code doesn't reproduce the problem, then it is leading everyone down the primrose path.